# Force as a vector

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors

> It is natural to assume that for three-dimensional motion, force, like acceleration, behaves like a vector. Although this turns out to be the case, it is not obviously true.

Why is not "obviously true" that force behaves like a vector?

Comment: It's obviously true *if* you assume Newton's 2nd law: it's not obviously true if you don't.

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/369817/

Comment: When you push a coffee cup with your finger you're pushing in a certain direction with a certain magnitude of force; hence representing force as a vector appears intuitive; whereas torque, a force applied to rotate the coffee-cup is not intuitively such a vector, we still represent it as such.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Mass and Newton's Second Law](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/369817) posted by the same user. Please do not post the same question more than once.